# C++ Ubuntu select() if serial interface has data on asynchronous read

Tags: c++, multithreading, ubuntu, asynchronous, serial-port

I´m writing an asynchronous serial data reader class for Ubuntu using C++ and termios and I´m facing difficulties checking is there is data available.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

class MySerialClass {

    public:
        MySerialClass(std::string port);
        virtual ~MySerialClass();

        void openSerial();
        void closeSerial();
        void configureSerial();
        void writeSerial(std::vector<char> data);
        void readSerial(std::vector<char> &data, unsigned int numBytes);

    private:

        int fd = 0; // The serial file descriptor
        fd_set fdset; // The set to check on select
        std::string portName = "";
};


MySerialClass::MySerialClass(std::string port) : portName(port) {}
MySerialClass::~MySerialClass() {}

void MySerialClass::openSerial()
{
    fd = open(portName.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    FD_ZERO(&fdset); 
    FD_SET(fd, &fdset); 
}

void MySerialClass::closeSerial()
{
    close(fd);
}

void MySerialClass::configureSerial()
{
    struct termios config = { 0 };

    tcgetattr(fd, &config);

    config.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
    config.c_oflag = 0;
    config.c_lflag = ICANON;

    config.c_cc[VINTR]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-c */
    config.c_cc[VQUIT]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-\ */
    config.c_cc[VERASE]   = 0;     /* del */
    config.c_cc[VKILL]    = 0;     /* @ */
    config.c_cc[VEOF]     = 4;     /* Ctrl-d */
    config.c_cc[VTIME]    = 0;     /* inter-character timer unused */
    config.c_cc[VMIN]     = 1;     /* blocking read until 1 character arrives */
    config.c_cc[VSWTC]    = 0;     /* '\0' */
    config.c_cc[VSTART]   = 0;     /* Ctrl-q */
    config.c_cc[VSTOP]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-s */
    config.c_cc[VSUSP]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-z */
    config.c_cc[VEOL]     = 0;     /* '\0' */
    config.c_cc[VREPRINT] = 0;     /* Ctrl-r */
    config.c_cc[VDISCARD] = 0;     /* Ctrl-u */
    config.c_cc[VWERASE]  = 0;     /* Ctrl-w */
    config.c_cc[VLNEXT]   = 0;     /* Ctrl-v */
    config.c_cc[VEOL2]    = 0;     /* '\0' */

    speed_t sp = B9600;
    config.c_cflag |= CSIZE;
    config.c_cflag |= CS8;

    cfsetispeed(&config, sp);
    cfsetospeed(&config, sp);

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &config);
}

void MySerialClass::writeSerial(std::vector<char> data)
{
    char buffer[1024];

    if (data.size() > 1024)
        return;

    int index = 0;
    for (char &item : data)
        buffer[index++] = item;

    unsigned int size = data.size();
    write(fd, &buffer[0], size);
}

void MySerialClass::readSerial(std::vector<char> &data, unsigned int numBytes)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    data.clear();

    if (numBytes > 1024)
        return;

    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    int ret = select(fd + 1, 0, 0, 0, &tv);

    std::cout << "Select returns: " << ret << std::endl;

    if (!ret)
        return;

    read(fd, &buffer[0], numBytes);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numBytes; i++)
        data.push_back(buffer[i]);
}

int main()
{
    MySerialClass serial("/dev/ttyS1");
    serial.openSerial();
    serial.configureSerial();

    while(1)
    {
        std::vector<char> retData;
        serial.readSerial(retData, 100);

        std::string retString(retData.begin(), retData.end());

        if (retString == "END")
        {
            serial.closeSerial();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles fine, but it never receives data as the `select()` statement always returns zero. The code with blocking option and without the `select()` works fine (just comment the select() line and remove `O_NODELAY` from `open()`).

I´m pretty sure this problem is related to the way `select()` is being used (it´s my first time with `select()`).

Can someone help me to solve that ? The code is available at [Coliru here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c0dea71beb14f96)

BTW: Another doubt I have relative to `select()` is that this class will be used on a multithreaded environmet. I need to make sure that each class instance will check only for its port busy (it´s own `fd`), no other threads port busy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't specify a fd_set to read. Try this:

```
fd_set readfs;    /* file descriptor set */

FD_ZERO(&readfs); /* clear the set */
FD_SET(fd, &readfs); /* put the fd in the set */
int ret = select(fd + 1, &readfs, 0, 0, &tv);
```

Edit: That should also solve your other question. Each select is only looking at the file descriptors you tell it to look at.

Gah. Bad English grammar, but it looks even worse corrected.